# Scroll view limit one border

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, bounce

The property `bounces` can limit scroll view border, but I want to limit one border, for example: I can drag over top border, but bottom can't. I have make it using two views, but I want to find a direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check scrollview's content offset if it is beyond bottom bounds using `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of `UIScrollView` and put bounce for scrollview check so it will bounce for top bounds.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
```

**Note :** Set `scrollview` delegate to `self` for your `scrollview` instance like so it will call this delegate method while scrolling . cheers :)

```
yourScrollviewInstance.delegate = self
```